# Setting up GIT for Symfony2 project: why add web/bundles folder to gitignore

Tags: git, symfony, gitignore

I am building my first Symfony2 project and I may be confused on the purpose of the `web/bundles` folder. According to Symfony2 documentation they say this is where static data goes like js libraries, css and images. This all makes sense but while you are still building that base layout isn't it a little annoying to have `/web/bundles` on the ignore list? In fact why even have it on the ignore list? bootstrap, parameters, cache, etc all makes sense to have on ignore because you don't want to cross development settings with production settings.

This is what symfony instructs you to add to the gitignore:

```
/web/bundles/
/app/bootstrap*
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
/vendor/
/app/config/parameters.yml
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason to put the `web/bundles` folder to ignore is that it's *generated* by running the `app/console assets:install web` command which is also run automatically at the end of the `bin/vendors install` run. Whatever you have in `YourBundle/Resources/public` goes to `web/bundles/your`.

If you don't want to install assets each time you change them while developing, use the `--symlink` argument:

```
app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to comment on Elnur Abdurrakhimov answer, but due to not enough reputation: `app/console assets:install web` removes everything in `web/` so make sure to copy everything to `src/<Bundle>/Resources/public` **before** execute the command the first time.